# iOS 8 Adaptive layout and constraints on custom design

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode7

I am trying to use Adaptive Layout to upgrade my project for iOS 8-9.
I have read and watch a lot of tutorials but all of them are explaining how to adapt a simple design with rectangles and centre them on the screen.
I don't know why I find it so difficult to understand how it works for my design.
This is my design in storyboard and how I would like to appear on all of the iPhones in portrait mode:
[image]

Can someone guide me how to properly build the constraints on this View? I might be able to understand the logic of constraints for real designs rather than rectangles which are centred in the screen. shall I start to design from Compact&Regular?

Comment: Question : Does you app work only for iPhones and only is portrait mode? What are your requirements for positioning the views? For eg, Where do you want to calculate button to appear? Always on the center of the screen? What about the requirements for the other views? THis information needs to be determined first before defining the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the views laid out for different iPhone screen sizes in portrait mode. I have made some assumptions about the rules for the placement of the views. You can see the constraints also in the screen print.

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I noticed that you use StackView which is not supported in iOS 8 (which I need to). Also Textfields size are equal but I need the one on the left to be bigger!

Comment: Ok, yes, we cant be using stackviews. Its easy to fix that though, just remove the textviews from the stackviews and set individual constraints for both of them.

For the width of the textfields, you can set a constraint to say they are of "Equal Widths" and then on one of the textfields, set the multiplier factor to be 0.5, then one text field will be twice the width of the other.